# Backbone View Architecture

Tags: backbone.js

I have 2 parts in my application:

1. A grid of players each with a thumbnail to click which activates a detail view on the left side of the page.
2. Detail view - activated when player is clicked on grid.

The model is very straightforward and will be read only. (Player model and Players collection)

The way I am thinking of organizing views is as follows:

1. AppView - main view that fetches collection (to create grid) and populates the grid. (JSONP  is done in model) and manages events for the grid such as pagination.
2. PlayerThumb View - The view that contains a thumbnail of player that can be clicked from inside the grid.
3. CardView - This view contains the players large picture as well as stats about the player.

My confusion is how do I communicate information to the card view when a player thumb view is clicked?

What is the responsibility of the AppView? Is it doing too much? Should I create a PlayerGridView? If this is the case, what would app view be used for?

Comment: app view for layout, and emit an event when thumb view is clicked which you'll listen from card ?

Comment: I think I got that, but the other part that is throwing me off is what should the AppView do? Should I have a gridView, CardView, and ThumbView?

Comment: Usually it's just a general layout for my app, without much.